# Find elements of one column in another

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Code I implemented compares two columns and copies the lines together if it finds matching values.

Currently, it compares about 100-150 lines and it takes around three minutes, sometimes more.

Is there is any faster method than `Range.Find()`?
Also it would be interesting to know what search algorithm this method is using.

File is saved on a server so that may increase the runtime.

The relevant part of my code:

```vb
For Each LineA In sheet1.Range("B1:B" & LastRowSheet1)
    
    Set LineB = sheet2.Range("B1:B" & LastRowSheet2).Find(LineA.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not LineB Is Nothing Then
        With sheet2
            .Range(.Cells(LineB.Row, 3), .Cells(LineB.Row, 12)).Copy sheet3.Range(sheet3.Cells(i, 4), sheet3.Cells(i, 13))
        End With
    
        With sheet1
            .Range(.Cells(LineA.Row, 2), .Cells(LineA.Row, 4)).Copy sheet3.Range(sheet3.Cells(i, 1), sheet3.Cells(i, 3))
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
        
   End If
   
Next LineA
```

Comment: So if there's any match, you copy the same value to sheet3 or you copy the entire row? Or do you want to copy each row from both sheets if it has a match, i.e. B1 in sheet1 has 5 matches in Sheet2 then you copy row 1 from Sheet1 5 times or just the one time with the 5 matched rows from sheet2?

Comment: Please show us the actual code not 'something like'.  Preferably a the smallest working example as outline by the SO guidelines on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Other options include `Application.Match` (which is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Match`). As far as speed, up to you to test!

Comment: There is always at most one match, and I merge both lines together as one line on sheet3. I edited the post for more clarity.

Comment: I'd suspect copy/pasting to cause slowness here, not the find.

Comment: Instead of iterating through cells assign the entire range to two Variants - they will then be arrays that you can traverse. Assign the matches to another Variant (array) and then copy to the third sheet on masse when completed

Comment: @CHill60 - an issue with arrays may be that OP wants to copy along the cells' formatting.

Comment: @BigBen - fair point. If that was the case I would keep a separate list of row references that I intend to "copy" across and then assign the formatting from those rows to the new list based on that list after assigining the values - still faster than using Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub find()
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, lookupSheet As Worksheet, resultSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataRange As Range, lookupRange As Range
Dim dataArray As Variant, lookupArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRowData As Long, lastRowLookup As Long, found As Long

Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set lookupSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set resultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

With dataSheet
    lastRowData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = .Range("B1:B" & lastRowData)
    dataArray = dataRange.Value
End With

With lookupSheet
    lastRowLookup = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set lookupRange = .Range("B1:B" & lastRowLookup)
    lookupArray = lookupRange.Value
End With

i = 1

For j = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 1)
    found = Application.Match(dataArray(j, 1), lookupArray, 0)
    If Not IsError(found) Then
        resultSheet.Range("D" & i & ":M" & i).Value = lookupSheet.Range("C" & found & ":L" & found).Value
        resultSheet.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value = dataSheet.Range("B" & j & ":D" & j).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

to copy column format

```
Sub CopyColumnFormats()
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim destRange As Range
    Dim srcCol As Range
    Dim destCol As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set srcRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:L1")
    Set destRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1:M1")
    
    For i = 1 To srcRange.Columns.Count
        Set srcCol = srcRange.Columns(i)
        Set destCol = destRange.Columns(i)
        srcCol.Copy
        destCol.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next i
    
    Set srcRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D1")
    Set destRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:C1")

    For i = 1 To srcRange.Columns.Count
        Set srcCol = srcRange.Columns(i)
        Set destCol = destRange.Columns(i)
        srcCol.Copy
        destCol.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Small change: I declared the "found" variable as a Variant, instead of Long, code wouldn't run otherwise. Can you explain, why this is so much faster? Because the code is only traversing arrays, instead of the columns? Or is it actually the way I tried to copy the values?

Comment: @Chris_A traversing using array is very fast, using match is faster than find, copy then pasting is usually slower

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

[image]

```vb
Sub LookupData()
    
    Const LKP_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const LKP_LEFT_COLUMNS_TO_EXCLUDE As Long = 1
    Const SRC_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    ' Your code...
    
    ' These two lines are just for this code to compile.
    Const LastRowSheet2 As Long = 3 ' Lookup
    Const LastRowSheet1 As Long = 4 ' Source
    
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = Sheet2.Range("B1:L" & LastRowSheet2) ' 3-12
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet1.Range("B1:D" & LastRowSheet1) ' 2-4
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = Sheet3.Range("A2")
    
    ' Write the values from the lookup range to an array.
    
    Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = lrg.Rows.Count
    Dim lcCount As Long: lcCount = lrg.Columns.Count
    Dim lData(): lData = lrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values ('keys') and their correcesponding
    ' row indexes ('items') to a dictionary.
    
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim lr As Long, lStr As String
    
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        lStr = CStr(lData(lr, LKP_COLUMN))
        If Len(lStr) > 0 Then
            If Not lDict.Exists(lStr) Then
                lDict(lStr) = lr
            End If
        End If
    Next lr
    
    ' The source data is also...
     
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    ' ... the left part of the destination so write it to an array
    ' and resize the array to accommodate the lookup data on the right.
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    Dim dcCount As Long:
    dcCount = srCount + lrCount - LKP_LEFT_COLUMNS_TO_EXCLUDE
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To srCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Loop through the source array and write the matching rows
    ' to the top of the destination array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long, sStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = Data(sr, SRC_COLUMN)
        If lDict.Exists(sStr) Then ' match found
            lr = lDict(sStr) ' retrieve the lookup row
            dr = dr + 1
            ' Write source.
            For c = 1 To scCount
                Data(sr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
            ' Write lookup.
            For c = 1 + LKP_LEFT_COLUMNS_TO_EXCLUDE To lcCount
                Data(sr, c + scCount - LKP_LEFT_COLUMNS_TO_EXCLUDE) _
                    = lData(lr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Write the result from the top of the array to the range.
   
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, dcCount)
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(drg.Worksheet.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Lookup is done.", vbInformation

End Sub
```